# If ASP.NET 5 is being renamed ASP.NET Core 1.0, what is a new ASP.NET project targeting full .NET framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, naming, asp.net5

The offical docs say:

> ASP.NET 5 is being renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0

But what if I create a new ASP .NET 5 project in VS2015 today in the the `project.json` only target the dnx451:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
  },
```

Surely this is not considered a "ASP .NET Core 1.0 project"! It is still possible to create ASP .NET 5 projects that do not use .NET Core and surely that won't be removed!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project templates have been split into full .NET (using the `net461` target framework) and .NET Core (using the `netcoreapp1.0` target framework).

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393147/targetting-netcoreapp-and-full-net-using-asp-net-core) question to see if both can be targeted at the same time.

[image]

Comment: So what is a project targeting net461 called?

Comment: See the updated image. The two templates have the same name, just the target framework is different.

Comment: So its called "ASP .NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)", that deserves the Oxymoron of the year award! :)