# Targetting netcoreapp And The Full net461 Using ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

In the recent ASP.Net Core RC2 Preview 1 release of the tooling, the project templates were split into full .NET Framework projects targeting `net461` and .NET Core projects targeting `netcoreapp1.0`.

In the previous world, both of these target frameworks were added in a single project. Can this still be done? What was the reason for splitting them up?

Comment: Without having tried out the new templates, I'd dare to say they were not split like you think they were. Before with the old tooling, there was only one "ASP.NET Web" Project template which had ASP.NET 4.5 (old WebForms, WebApi2, MVC5) templates and the new ASP.NET 5 (now ASP.NET Core) templates in. It's was just misleading as this implied that ASP.NET Core were a new version of the older ASP.NET MVC/WebApi. But they aren't really compatible and the new ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite. That's why all versions got reset to 1.0. There is no MVC6 anymore, it's ASP.NET Core MVC (1.0.0)

Comment: You can still create ASP.NET Core Web project and target full .NET framework or just .NET Core (or both, depending on your dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both in a single project: Yes you can do that. Create one of them, add the other other framework in the project.json like before. Like Tseng outlined, it is just the default Windows template which no longer support it.

Why they splitted up: **IMHO**: I think the combined view confused many people. Also the upcoming change moving from project.json/xproj to csproj may influence this.